# Assigning a 2D array (of pointers) to a variable in an object for access in C++?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, multidimensional-array

I'm sorry if I didn't pick a descriptive or concise name. A lot of questions sound similar, but I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for. What I want to do is store a 2D array of pointers somewhere and assign a variable in some object to that array to be able to access it.

Here's some example code that has the same compile error I'm getting with a bigger project.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct X{
    float n, * b[8][8];
    X(){
        n = 1;
        b[1][5] = &n;
        cout << *(b[1][5]) << endl;
    }
    void Set(float * c[8][8]){
        b = c;
        cout << *(b[1][5]) << endl;
    }
};
main(){
    float m, * a[8][8];
    m = 2;
    a[1][5] = &m;
    X obj;
    obj.Set(a);
}
```

What I want to happen in this code is that an X object starts with its own 2D array, whose value pointed to by b[1][5] should be printed as "1". Then the main method's 2D array, a, is passed to the object's Set() method and assigned to its array variable. The value pointed to by b[1][5] should then be printed as "2".

However, I can't figure out what type the Set() parameter, c, should be. I get

```
error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘float* (*)[8]’ to ‘float* [8][8]’
```

when I try to compile. As for why I want to do this, I'm trying to use an array of pointers to objects, not floats, but it's the same error.

Comment: You have a problem with pointers here: You have an array of arrays of pointers, but you don't set the pointer to point to anything. You do however assign a value to the location of this uninitialized pointer, which results in so called _undefined behavior_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct X{
    float n;
    float* (*b)[8];
    X(){
        n = 1;
        b = new float*[8][8];
        b[1][5] = &n;
        cout << *(b[1][5]) << endl;
    }
    void Set(float * c[8][8]){
        delete[] b;
        b = c;
        cout << *(b[1][5]) << endl;
    }
};
main(){
    float m, * a[8][8];
    m = 2;
    a[1][5] = &m;
    X obj;
    obj.Set(a);
}
```

Here, `X` stores a pointer to a 1D array, which we are treating as a pointer to the first element of a 2D array - i.e. as just a 2D array.

In `X`'s constructor, `X` allocates its own array with `new` and sets its pointer to point to that. When calling `Set()`, `X` deletes its own array, and sets its pointer to point to the array provided by the caller.

The only thing to watch out for is, if you call `Set()` again, *that* array will in turn be deleted (which will blow up if that array is a stack array, like in this case). So, it might be advisable to separate the line that does `delete[] b` into its own member function, and call it only when necessary.

Comment: I'd vote this up, but I don't have enough reputation yet. That's a weird way to declare b, but it works! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Now I have enough. There you go.

Comment: @MrMormon: The type of `b` here is [pointer-to]-[array-of-8]-[pointers-to]-[float]. The parentheses are necessary because `float** b[8]` would be [array-of-8]-[pointers-to]-[pointers-to]-[float]. See the difference? (Note that spaces make no difference).

Comment: Parentheses can change the "pointer chain" order, got it. Confusing if you don't know that, powerful if you do, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with set is that you need to copy the array contents - just doing `b=c` can't do what you want.

```
void Set(float * c[8][8]){
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<8; ++i) {
      for(unsigned int j=0; j<8; ++j) {
        b[i][j] = c[i][j];
      }
    }
    cout << *(b[1][5]) << endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't want a copy, though. I want access to the one in the main method.

Comment: @MrMormon: That's inconsistent with your desire that "an X object starts with its own 2D array". An X object either stores an actual 2D array, or just a pointer to a 2D array that's stored elsewhere. If the former, you need to copy the array in Set(). If the latter, then an X object can't start with it's *own* 2D array.

Comment: Sorry. What I meant is that X obviously needs an array variable if it's going to be able to access the array in main(). I'm really trying to avoing using a pointer to an array. That adds (*array) everywhere.

Comment: @MrMormon: So copying the array in Set() solves your problem, right?

Comment: I want access to the array in main. A copy wouldn't reflect a change in the pointers in array a.

Comment: @MrMormon: Then you need to store a pointer to an array in `X`, not an array. I don't see any way around that.

Comment: I thought doing "float a[1], b[1]; b = a" would make b point to the same stuff as a? For example.

Comment: @MrMormon: In your example `a` is an array, not a pointer. You can't make it point to another array, you can only assign new values to its elements.

Comment: So what does "float a[1], b[1]; b = a;" do?

Comment: @MrMormon: `float a[1], b[1]; b = a;` fails to compile with GCC 4.6 with the error `invalid array assignment`. Earlier versions of GCC may have allowed this, but what they did for it is copy the array element-by-element.

Comment: Weird. I thought C++ was flexible. I guess I do have to use stupid pointer syntax. Thank you.

Comment: @MrMormon: You can avoid the "stupid pointer syntax" for the most part. I'm writing an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

There are several bugs I think..
Firstly, in Set() function you have assigned an array name. But array name should not be used as a variable. You can solve this by making 2D array of pointer b as a pointer to 1D array of pointer like float * (*b)[8]...

Secondly, when you send the 2D array of pointer as argument of Set() function it is decaying into a pointer to 1D array of pointer i.e something like this float *(*a)[8]. so you have to make the formal argument of Set() function a pointer to 1D array of pointers like void Set(float * (*c)[8])...

And finally there is a thing your float variable m inside main is a local to main , so when control pass to Set() function I think the compiler cant find the value(may be deallocated) in the m...so it outputs undefined or give run time error..you can solve this by making m a static version. i.e by declaring static float m...

In total make your code like following :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct X{
    float n, *(*b)[8];
    X(){
        n = 1;
        b[1][5] = &n;
        cout << *(b[1][5]) << endl;
    }
    void Set(float * (*c)[8]){
        b = c;
        cout << *(b[1][5]) << endl;
    }
};
main(){
    float * a[8][8];
    static float m;
    m = 2;
    a[1][5] = &m;
    X obj;
    obj.Set(a);
}
```

This will output correctly :)

Comment: The problem here is that `X`'s constructor does not actually set `b` to point to anything. On the line `b[1][5] = &n;`, you are accessing and writing to garbage memory. See my answer for how I avoid that problem.

Comment: I have made m static and no explicit memory allocation and it is working in my GNU compiler..if you make m global then also working.. then how it is working? in line b[1][5]=&n , b is pointing to n which is assigned value 1 previously. The main problem here was in with assignment of pointer array and i have explained it in my post ...:)

Comment: I get a segfault. Platform-dependent undefined behavior, probably.

Comment: The problem is not with the `= &n` part, it's with the `b[1][5]` part. `b` itself doesn't point to anything yet, so even doing `b[1]` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: sorry brother please explain it for me. I am thinking he is pointing to something by executing statement b[1][5] = &n. I am sure, I am missing what you want to clarify..

Comment: Yes, `b[1][5] = &n;` makes `b[1][5]` point to `n`. However, `b[1][5]` itself doesn't exist, because `b` doesn't point to anything. It's similar to doing `int* i; i[0] = &something;`.